# I fill "basket" array with objects. but then, when i try to get array lenght it return me "undefined" value

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fzUt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N3KW.png)

I fill "basket" array with objects, but then, when i try to get array lenght it return me "undefined" value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndXZB.png)

The lengh is pale here, is problem connect with that?

Comment: Please post your code in code blocks. Not in an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the property is `length`, not `lenght`.

So,

```
console.log(basket.length)
```